# Can't download dynamically created ZIP archive

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, archiverjs

I'm trying to dynamically write an output from MySQL queries to archive. Here's my code:

```
var async = require("async");
var mysql = require("mysql");
var express = require("express"); 
var archiver = require("archiver");

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
   password : 'password',
   database : 'test'
});

app.get('/file', (req, res) => {

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
        'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=archive-name.zip'

    var zip = archiver('zip', {
        zlib: { level: 9 } 
    });

    zip.pipe(res); 

    zip.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Archive wrote %d bytes', zip.pointer());
    });

    const queriesArray = ["SELECT * FROM tb1", "SELECT * FROM tb2"];

    async.forEachOf(queriesList, (query) => {
        connection.query(query, (err, results) => {
            if(!err) {
                zip.append(JSON.stringify(results), {name: `${query}.txt`})
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error while performing Query");
            }
        })
    }, function(err) {
           if (err) {
               console.log("error")
           }
           else {
               zip.finalize();
           }
       }) 
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 7000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Listen on port ' + port);
})
```

This code is supposed to create a zip archive with multiple text files. The user visiting `/file` page must be presented with a file download prompt but it seems like `zip.finalize()` isn't working so I can't download created archive (download starts when I'm visiting `/file` but doesn't finish). Why won't my code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your callback function is never called as [`forEachOf`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOf) doesn't know it has finished all the async tasks.

The iteratee function has a final argument that is a callback function that you must call in order for it to know that that particular async process has finished, but you never use it.

> https://caolan.github.io/async/global.html#AsyncFunction
>
> An "async function" in the context of Async is an asynchronous
>   function with a variable number of parameters, with the final
>   parameter being a callback. `(function (arg1, arg2, ..., callback) {})`
>   The final callback is of the form `callback(err, results...)`, **which
>   must be called once the function is completed.**

So to fix your code make sure to call the callback method of your iteratee function inside the callback of your query call

```
async.forEachOf(queriesList, (query,key,callback) => {
    connection.query(query, (err, results) => {
        if(!err) {
            zip.append(JSON.stringify(results), {name: `${query}.txt`})
        }
        else {
            console.log("Error while performing Query");
        }
        callback();
    })
```